# In iOS openGL, how can one create a blend mode similar to kCGBlendModeDarken?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, alphablending

On a white background, drawing lines using kCGBlendModeDarken darkens the areas where **different** colors meet, like this:

[image: darken blend mode]

I am trying to recreate this using openGL in iOS, but I don't know how to set the glBlendFunc properties to achieve this. The openGL documentation is hard to grasp for a beginner.

What would be the proper way to achieve this in openGL ES 1_X on iOS?

Comment: So, did you get Darken blending mode in iOS? if so, do share.

Comment: There are plenty of blending modes available in Quartz2D, take a look at [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGContextSetBlendMode)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `kCGBlendModeDarken` is just a regular darkening blend mode, the same effect can be achieved in OpenGL using these two commands:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glBlendEquation(GL_MIN);
```

Depending on your version of OpenGL, `GL_MIN` might be `GL_FUNC_MIN`.

Comment: Thanks, but neither GL_MIN or GL_FUNC_MIN are available in openGL ES for iOS.

Comment: hmmm, strange... OpenGL ES is missing min and max equations. Check to see if there's an extension for that... I think the other answer might have the proper extension, but you still need to set the blend func to  `GL_ONE, GL_ONE`

Comment: It's strange, as the GL_MAX_EXT works, but the GL_MIN_EXT makes everything disappear. Maybe there is some other way to do this? I've not found many examples on OpenGL ES programming for the iPhone :(

Comment: The issue might be because your clear color has alpha 0. When anything is drawn, the min between the alphas is always 0. Looking at your drawing code would be helpful, as I can only make guesses about what's wrong without it.

Comment: I'm using the GLPaint example from Apple as a starting point: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Listings/Classes_PaintingView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328-Classes_PaintingView_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

Comment: based on that example, I was right... in `erase` it's calling `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);`. Change that to `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` . If that doesn't have an effect, add the same `glClearColor` call to the method that initializes everything.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this again. When calling `glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)` (I need a white background) I get black squares when I paint: !http://machineboy.com/bilder/gl_min_ext.png

Comment: At this point the error could be one of many things, try playing around with your rendering code and the clear color to see if you find any configuration that shows something different.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `glBlendEquationOES(GL_MIN_EXT);`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not getting this to work. I'm modifying the GLpaint example by Apple by setting `eaglLayer.opaque = NO;` and then `glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBlendEquationOES(GL_MIN_EXT);` but now painting on the screen is invisible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the GLpaint example, but the func sounds roughly right. What I'm drawing doesn't have any alpha info. Does GL_MAX_EXT (lighten) work?

Comment: Yes, GL_MAX_EXT works, and seems to brighten (yellowish white) where the green and red lines cross. GL_MIN_EXT makes nothing appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);
```